# Retrieve checkbox array from WordPress meta field

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, object

After saving array through WordPress meta box it has been saved like

```
a:4:{i:0;s:3:"226";i:1;s:3:"229";i:2;s:3:"228";i:3;s:3:"227";}
```

I want to retrieve and loop this array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a serialized array. To unserialize use `unserialize` function.

```
$str = 'a:4:{i:0;s:3:"226";i:1;s:3:"229";i:2;s:3:"228";i:3;s:3:"227";}';
print_r (unserialize($str); // Array ( [0] => 226 [1] => 229 [2] => 228 [3] => 227 )
```

Then you can go through using `foreach`, for example.

Comment: btw, there is also the [`maybe_unserialize()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/maybe_unserialize/) function, which unserializes the data only if it was serialized.

Comment: @over-engineer: it's possible, I'm not a WP developer, I'm PHP developer :-) We can add a condition around, or... the main point was the `unserialize` function.